# Add unique runid to .jtl file for every Jmeter run

Tags: jmeter

I am running below jmeter command using power shell

```
$runid =$build_number
jmeter -Jsample_variables=$runid -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

In the .Jtl result , I could see column added with build_number value as column name and column values are empty.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) but not assigning any value to it

1. Add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element to your test plan and define `runid` variable there using [`${__P(runid,)}` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as the value:

   [image]
2. Amend your JMeter startup command as:

   ```
   jmeter -Jsample_variables=runid -Jrunid=123456 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
3. That's it, once test finishes you should be able to see the `runid` column with the appropriate value:

   [image]

Comment: once custom fields are added to .jtl file , aggregate report is not getting generated from .jtl using -g -o command. Any thoughts on this.

Comment: I think that given you have the same [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) it should not be a problem to generate HTML Reporting Dashboard. If you overridden some values via -J command-line arguments - you need to do the same for the dashboard generation (or put the changes into [user.properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) file). I also think that this problem doesn't have anything in common with the original question so you should rather raise new one instead of hijacking